# Sending an Email using gmail through Java

Tags: java, email, gmail

I am trying to send email through java using this code :

```
package send_email;
import java.util.Properties;  
import javax.mail.*;  
import javax.mail.internet.*;  
/**
 *
 * @author A
 */
public class Send_email {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        String host="smtp.gmail.com";  
  final String user="***@gmail.com";//change accordingly  
  final String password="****";//change accordingly  

  String to="*******@gmail.com";//change accordingly  

   //Get the session object  
   Properties props = new Properties();  
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host);  
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  

   Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,  
    new javax.mail.Authenticator() {  
      protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {  
    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);  
      }  
    });  

   //Compose the message  
    try {  
     MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);  
     message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));  
     message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));  
     message.setSubject("javatpoint");  
     message.setText("This is simple program of sending email using JavaMail API");  

    //send the message  
     Transport.send(message);  

     System.out.println("message sent successfully...");  

     } catch (MessagingException e) {e.printStackTrace();} 
    }

}
```

But I get the following error :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 25, response: 554
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1694)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:525)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at send_email.Send_email.main(Send_email.java:48)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have allowed port 25 through firewall and then I have tested it using telnet " telnet smtp.gmail.com 25 " but I get this error 
554 OutgoingFilter "You are temporarily deferred due to sending spam or virus pl
ease contact 16333 for more information"

So how do I fix this error?

Edit : I am now getting this error through Telnet "421 Cannot connect to SMTP server 108.177.15.109 (108.177.15.109:25), connect er
ror 10060

Connection to host lost.
"
Edit _2 : I found that the port for gmail SMTP is 587 and I have changed the session object accordingly to

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
p.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
p.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
p.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required","true");
```

This code was provided down there. However I get the following error :

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1652)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:534)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:313)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:172)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:121)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:190)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:120)
    at send_email.Send_email.main(Send_email.java:52)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1640)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:503)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:443)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1647)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:237)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1622)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    ... 23 more
```

However the telenet when connecting through this new port gives me the following :   220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP a24sm5897091wmb.29 - gsmtp
Which I think this means that I am connected through telnet.

Comment: It's related to your gmail account and google policies. Perhaps I'd call 16333.

Comment: How many times have you run this program in the last 24 hours?  If you try to send mail too many times in a short period, it makes sense that a mail relay would treat you as a spam source.

Answer (score 0):

Try these settings

```
Properties p = new Properties();
p.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
p.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
p.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
p.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
p.put("mail.smtp.starttls.required","true");
```

Comment: I get this error javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the following techniques to get the SMTP server:

1. Install and use any SMTP server such as Postcast server, Apache
   James server, email server, etc
2. Use the SMTP server provided by the host provider e.g. my SMTP
   the server is mail.xxx.com
3. Use the SMTP Server provided by other companies e.g. Gmail etc.

For sending the email using JavaMail API, you need to load the two jar files:
- mail.jar 
- activation.jar
Below is the example

```
import java.util.*; 
import javax.mail.*; 
import javax.mail.internet.*; 
import javax.activation.*;

    public class TestSendEmail {

       public static void main(String [] args) {    
          // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
          String to = "abcd@gmail.com";

          // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
          String from = "test@gmail.com";

          // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
          String host = "localhost";

          // Get system properties
          Properties properties = System.getProperties();

          // Setup mail server
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

          // Get the default Session object.
          Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          try {
             // Create a default MimeMessage object.
             MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

             // Set From: header field of the header.
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

             // Set To: header field of the header.
             message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

             // Set Subject: header field
             message.setSubject(Subject Line!");

             // Now set the actual message
             message.setText("actual message");

             // Send message
             Transport.send(message);
             System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
          } catch (MessagingException mex) {
             mex.printStackTrace();
          }    } }
```